# Adding expressjs to a custom reactjs application

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

I have bough a pre-built template from third party vendor and it is a big and comprehsine reactjs application. Now I need to add some backend capabilities to it by using express.js. I do not know how to change that application

the structure for my reactjs application is as follow:

```
/node_modules
/public
/src
package.json
```

it is a simpem react application and israt with react-scripts start by npm start command. All the file in react is javascript files and there are no HTML files there. Does anyone know  an article or a guidance how to add exressjs backend to my custom reactjs application?

Answer (score 0):

You must follow the separation of concerns principle and create node (express) backend application separately, and react communicates with the node using APIs.

Else create a new folder naming your application, create 2 folders inside, server and client, copy react application folder in client and node application in server like below

```
/MyAPP
    /Client
        /node_modules
        /public
        /src
        package.json
    /Server
        /node_modules
        /src
        app.js
        package.json
```

Comment: How to nvigate between two applications whie both use javascript? perhaps, can you give me some elaboration through some sample codes?

Comment: on youtube or google, you can search for MERN Stack tutorial, you will easily get some idea

Answer (score 0):

## TL;DR;

keep both applications separated to there own git repository and treat them as separate projects. Add `dev-server` to your frontend project and proxy all API requests to the backend project.

---

Today most web applications are using `Reverse-Proxy` to serve both frontend and backend on the same domain (each one still has its own server).

```
// prod
                  Client
                 (Browser)
                     +
                     |
                     |  MyDomain.com
                     v
            +--------+--------+
            |  Reverse Proxy  |
            |     (Nginx)     |
            +--+---------+----+
               |         |
    BE_IP:3000 |         | BE_IP:8080
               v         v
      +--------+--+    +-+----------+
      |  Backend  |    |  Frontend  |
      |   (TBD)   |    |  (React)   |
      +-----------+    +------------+
```

This pattern should be used in your dev environment as well. Luckily [`dev-server`](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/) does just that (and has many helpful tricks for local development).

```
// dev
                  Client
                 (Browser)
                     +
                     |
                     |  localhost:9000
                     v
            +--------+--------+
            |  Reverse Proxy  |
            |   (dev-server)  |
            +--+---------+----+
               |         |
localhost:3000 |         | localhost:8080
               v         v
      +--------+--+    +-+----------+
      |  Backend  |    |  Frontend  |
      |   (TBD)   |    |  (React)   |
      +-----------+    +------------+
```

How to implement this into your code:

1. Create separate projects for each application (one for front and one for back)
2. Add `dev-server` to your frontend project and serve the `/public` directory (flow this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/)
3. create a backend project (keep it simple for now)
4. setup `dev-server` to redirect all request that starts with `/api` to the API server (flow this https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy)